# How can I trigger Safari to save email and password at registration and autofill it when logging in again?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently working on my very first Flask web app, which includes an email form.

I would like to know what specific triggers Safari looks for in my code so that it

1. Offers to save email and password after registration
2. Autocompletes email and password, when using the login form.

My registration form makes safari suggests an email at the right place (hurray, don't know why though) and you can even have it create a safe password randomly. After registration there is no dialog though to offer to save the submitted data.

**Registration.html**

```
 <form method="POST" action="">
        <input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="Ijg2MTQ3MDViZmVlhNGiNDg5ZTY1ODczZjQyODJiNjMwMGUi.YlI1pw.4vZVCPQbwSb4-0jD2BpQ1U0">
        <fieldset>
            <div >
                <label class="form-control-label" for="username">Name</label>
                    <input  id="username" maxlength="20" minlength="2" name="username" required type="text" value="">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                    <input  id="email" name="email" required type="text" value="">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input  id="password" name="password" required type="password" value="">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label  for="confirm_password">Confirm password:</label>
                    <input id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password" required type="password" value="">
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div>
            <input class="button" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Create Account">
        </div>
    </form>
```

My login form does not evoke any autocomplete feature. (Actually Safari even mistakes the email input for another password input for some reason)

**Login.html**

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="Ijg2MTQ3MDViZmVlNDFhNQwOTViNDg5ZTDczZjQyODJiNjMwMGUi.YlHp2w.8MT2N8Otm-1dZT0tVlivh8h4">
    <fieldset type=email>
        <div>
            <label for="email">Email: </label>
                <input id="email" name="email" required type="email" value="">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="password">Password: </label>
                <input id="password" name="password" required type="password" value="">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div>
        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Log in">
    </div>
</form>
```

I've tried

```
autocomplete = "username"
```

as suggested everywhere and also tested setting all other attributes like name, title, placeholder and so on. Never worked.

What am I missing out?

Comment: Have you tried using `autocomplete="on"` in form tag? In my case I'm using firefox browser, the above code works fine and auto saves login info.

Comment: Yes, tried that but doesn't work either on Safari. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Ok , have you tried saving form info on other sites? Might be some settings issue. Just try to create account on any popular site and check if it auto save login info or not.

Comment: That's the thing. Safari's autocomplete works like a charm everywhere but just not on my own site. You got any other suggestions? @TechnicalShubham

Comment: I'm confident that there is no error in the code because on my firefox browser it works fine. I think the problem is somewhere in your browser setting. Maybe you have blocked autocomplete for this site in settings!